# How to download file from tomcat server by javascript?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, download

I saved a text file in my Tomcat folder, 
**c:\program files/apache software foundation/tomcat7.0/test/test.txt**

I can only open it in the browser on my own PC.

How can I download and save it to my local disk,for example: **f:\test.txt**.

Can I use Javascript only?
Any sample code?

Thanks a million!

Comment: You cannot open it from other PC's unless you upload it to a live server. Once you upload to the server you can get the content of the text file using ajax, but to simply download the file you dont need javascript: you can use something like this: http://example.com/data/data.txt

Comment: @sajay how can i upload it to a server? could it be the tomcat server? when using ajax, how can i link it to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All webserver support ajax. You can try ajax from your local webserver only.  To upload to a server you need to buy domain name and webspace. Contact any webhosting company, they will guide you, for eg: http://godaddy.com/. Below is the ajax code to read text file from your server

```
 var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/data/data.txt", true);
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
        if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
          allText = txtFile.responseText; 
          lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // Will separate each line into an array
        }
      }
    }
    txtFile.send(null);
```